# Removing specific CDI managed beans from session

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2

I have some `@SessionScoped` CDI beans. Previously all of them were JSF managed beans (changed from JSF managed beans to CDI managed beans).

I was doing like the following to remove some session scoped JSF managed after a user successfully places an online order.

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = context.getSessionMap();

sessionMap.remove("cartBean");
sessionMap.remove("orderItems");
sessionMap.remove("reviewOrderBean");
sessionMap.remove("intermediateLocaleBean");
sessionMap.remove("localeBean");
sessionMap.remove("currencyRateBean");
sessionMap.remove("currency");
```

So that everything is set to default after order processing completes. This is irrelevant to destroying/invalidating the entire HTTP session where the user must not be logged out after order processing terminates successfully.

---

Unlike JSF managed beans, CDI beans are stored into server's memory by some CDI manager implementation like Weld. Therefore, they are not available in a session map - `Map<String, Object>`.

How can this be simulated anyway regarding CDI beans?

---

**UPDATE :**

[The Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.1.0.Final/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e647) :

> Keep in mind that once a bean is bound to a context, it remains in
>   that context until the context is destroyed. **There is no way to
>   manually remove a bean from a context.** If you don't want the bean to
>   sit in the session indefinitely, consider using another scope with a
>   shorted lifespan, such as the request or conversation scope.

So I assume, it is hard to manually destroy a bean without destroying something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CDI 1.1 introduced an `AlterableContext` interface with a `destroy(Bean<T>)` method.

Get the session context via `beanManager.getContext(SessionScoped.class)`, downcast to `AlterableContext` and then invoke `destroy()` with the appropriate bean type.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify Harald's answer:

```
@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;
.....
AlterableContext ctxSession = (AlterableContext) beanManager.getContext(SessionScoped.class);
for (Bean<?> bean : beanManager.getBeans(YourSessionBeanToBeDestroyedClass.class)) {
    Object instance = ctxSession.get(bean);
    if (instance != null)
        ctxSession.destroy(bean);
}
```